# SQL syntax error 1064 when synchronizing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with MySQL Workbench and I just added a new table in my MySQL Model. 
When I try to synchronize with the database I get the following error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci' at line 5

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NAW`.`HTML` (
   `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `HTML` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
    SPATIAL INDEX () 
)   ENGINE = InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
    COLLATE = utf8_general_ci

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed
```

If anyone sees what is wrong it would be great!

Comment: Problem is that only myisam storage engine is supported for spatial index refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html Change the engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NAW`.`HTML` (   
   `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `HTML` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
    SPATIAL INDEX (`ID`) 
)   ENGINE = MyISAM 
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
    COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Ty for the response but when I use this I get the following error:  Error 1464: The used table type doesn't support SPATIAL indexes

Comment: @Daanvn : the documentation @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html says that you need to use "MyISAM" engine for the SPATIAL indexes. Try changing your database engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't at this time (5.6) use spatial index with the innoDb engine, use MyISam engine instead. 
However, you can use the spatial data types with InnoDb since 5.0.6

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `=` signs from the character settings.

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NAW`.`HTML` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HTML` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  SPATIAL INDEX ())
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'
```

Comment: Ty for your fast response but this still gives the same error :<